# How to redefine/override initialized variables in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization, global-variables

One of my applications loads a yml file as a global variable in config/environment.rb so that the variable could be used globally, like this.

CFILE = YAML::load(File.open('path/to/the/file'))

Now I need to periodically reload the file to the same variable, since the file would be periodically modified. I've tried adding a rake task with the same line above but it doesn't really make the change.

How can I update the variable?

---

[Solved] Resolved with CFILE.replace new_cfile

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to do that.  :)  But, you can!

```
Object.send(:remove_const, :CFILE)
```

Then redefine as if it were never there.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. I left the rails console open, manually ran the rake job with the remove_const line and the define line. and check the variable again in the console, it's the same... should I replace the Object to sth else?

Comment: The console is a separate process - there's no way for you to remotely change the value of another processes' variable.  Well, not without some sort of IPC mechanism, of course.  If you want to detect a change in some file and then reload the constant in another process, that is a whole different question.

Comment: thanks for the response, Dave. So you mean the rails server process/thread would never get updated with the reload above. is there other way that you know of to dynamically change global variable? if that's not possible i guess my last resort would be restarting the server when the change is detected...

Comment: The basic scheme is this: you note the timestamp of your config file in your process.  "Every now and then" (every request maybe, every so often), you compare the file's timestamp to the one stored.  If it's newer, you undefine the constant and reread the file.  However, at this point, you're pretty far removed from the definition of "constant" and your coworkers will likely think you insane for doing this.  :)

Comment: I would also add that the question you're asking here now is not at all related to the original question.  Typically you should make your questions as specific to your problem as possible, otherwise you end up with these long comment threads instead of a direct answer in the first place.